# Is a Amazon Machine Images (AMI's) static or it's code be modified and rebuilt

Tags: amazon-ami

I have a customer who wishes me to do some customisations of the erp system opentaps, which they used via opentaps Amazon Elastic Computing Cloud (EC2) images, I've only worked with it on a normal server and don't know anything about images in the cloud. When I ssh in with the details the client gave me there is no sign of the erp installation directory I'd expect to see. I did originally expect that the image wouldn't be accessible, but the client assured me it was. I suppose they could be confused.
Would one have to create a new image and swap it out or is there a way to alter the source and rebuild like on a normal server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is not quite clear to me here. First of all EC2 images running in the cloud are just like normal virtual servers, so If you have an access to the running instance there is no difference between instance in the cloud and instance on another pc in your home for example.
You have to find out how opentaps are installed on the provided amis, then do your modifications, create an image from the modified instance and save it to s3 for backup if necessary.

If you want to start with fresh instance, you can start up any linux/windows distro on the EC2, install opentaps yourself your way and you are done.

Comment: Cool thanks, I expected the image to have SunJDK installed because you can't compile opentaps with OpenJDK, but clearly they got it on there without ever building it. Also the lib folders had read only permissions ... I suppose that has to do with it being an image... other then that there is no difference